# What is the difference between self and object parameters in __repr__ method?

Tags: python

I already know the difference between old-style class (class Foo()...) and new-style class (class Foo(object)...). But, what is the difference between that :

```
class Foo(object):
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'foo'
```

and

```
class Foo(object):
  def __repr__(object):
    return 'foo'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that in one case you called the variable that holds the instance `self` and in another case you called it `object`. That's the only difference.

The `self` variable is explicit in Python, and you can call it whatever you want. `self` is just the convention everyone uses for readability.

For example, this works just fine:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(bippity, colour):
...     bippity.colour = colour
...   def get_colour(_):
...     return _.colour
... 
>>> f = Foo('Blue')
>>> f.get_colour()
'Blue'
```

But it's pretty damn confusing. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is like saying;

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a="foo"
    def __repr__(bar):
        return bar.a
```

The variable name `bar` has no meaning whatsoever. It is just a reference to `self`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the name of the first parameter in a class method is merely a convention, you can name it anything you want.  **BUT DON'T**.  Always name it `self`, or you will be confusing everyone.  In particular, your example names it `object` which obscures a built-in name, and so is doubly bad.